# Wrapping an existing task with custom tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose I have two tasks, `doStart` and `doStop`, and I want to wrap an existing task (e.g. `test`) in these tasks. The following does not work:

```
test := Def.sequential(doStart, test, doStop).value
```

It fails at runtime with an error about unresolved setting key. I think this is actually quite natural, because `Def.sequential` expands into a nested sequence of `Def.taskDyn`, and since the `test` task is referenced in the middle task, its "new" value is requested, but at this moment it is apparently unavailable:

```
test := Def.taskDyn {
  doStart.value
  Def.taskDyn {
    test.value
    doStop
  }
}.value
```

If I introduce a temporary task and wrap it instead of `test`:

```
val _testOriginal = taskKey[Unit]("Used for wrapping.")

_testOriginal := test.value

test := Def.sequential(doStart, _testOriginal, doStop)
```

then I do not get the error but I get what seems like an infinite loop because `doStart` is then executed but SBT hangs indefinitely without invoking the original `test` task. This also seems natural because `_testOriginal` depends on the current value of `test`, not the original one.

The only "solution" I see now is to introduce my own tasks named like `testWrapped`, `testQuickWrapped`, etc. and tell the users of my build to use them instead of `test`/`testQuick`/etc., but I really don't want to do it. So, how do I wrap an existing task?

Answer (score 1):

```
test := doStop.dependsOn(test.dependsOn(doStart)).value
```

---

Though FYI, in the case of tests, you could make `doStart` and `doStop` not tasks, but rather vanilla functions, and use the provided `testOptions` facility.

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup(() => ...)

testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup(() => ... )
```

Comment: Indeed, the `dependsOn` trick does seem to work, thanks! Is it possible to do the same with `testQuick`/`testOnly` which are input tasks?